Brightway2 and ecoinvent 3.10 -- unlinked exchanges without username/password
Trying to import the ecoinvent 3.10 cutoff database in brightway2==2.4.6 with the latest bw2io version 0.8.12
if 'ecoinvent 3.10 cutoff' in bw.databases:
    print("Database has already been imported")
else:
    ei = bw.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(path, 'ecoinvent-3.10-cutoff')
    ei.apply_strategies()
    ei.statistics()
    ei.write_database()

results in
23523 datasets
743409 exchanges
4034 unlinked exchanges
   Type biosphere: 62 unique unlinked exchanges

It is basically the same problem as in Brightway2 and ecoinvent 3.10 -- unlinked exchanges though i cannot use the proposed way of the answer, because my university only supplied me with the ecoinvent data, not the username/password for it.
I experienced something similar also with ecoinvent 3.8 dataset, but using the fitting version of bw2io helped to have 0 unlinked exchanges.

The strong coupling between bw2io and ecoinvent releases was a design mistake, and new bw2io releases should be considered independent of ecoinvent in general, and definitely not tied to a specific release. This in turn means that bw2setup() should be deprecated in favor of more explicit choice of elementary flow lists and corresponding LCIA implementations.
The ideal case would be to have a valid ecoinvent license and credentials, as ecoinvent specifically and the data world in general is moving towards APIs instead of distributing data archives. We can discuss whether or not this is a good thing, but it is certainly a trend.
Instead of using bw2setup, you can install a base Brightway project with a specific version of both the ecoinvent elementary flows and LCIA impact categories using bw2io.remote:
import bw2io
bw2io.remote.install_project(
    project_name="call me something",
    project_key="ecoinvent-3.10-biosphere", 
    # This should get less ugly in the future
    projects_config={"ecoinvent-3.10-biosphere": "ecoinvent-3.10-biosphere.bw2.tar.gz"}
)

You can do the same with 3.8 and 3.9.1 - with these you can even omit the projects_config bit.
Don't forget to switch to your new project before adding data. Note that in this project the biosphere database is labelled explicitly (instead of the biosphere3 indeterminate mess) ecoinvent-3.10-biosphere. It is set in preferences as the default biosphere, but you may need to adjust your import code to match against this database name.
